# Is there a way to initialize multiple variables in Java?

Tags: java

For example, if I have the code:

```
public class Practice {
    
    private int num0;
    private int num1;
    private int num2;
    private int num3;
    
    public Practice() {
        num0 = 0 + 0 + 0 + 0;
        num1 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1;
        num2 = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2;
        num3 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use a loop or some other way to make the initialization less lengthy? Like if I had 40 nums, would I need to type this whole thing out?

Comment: [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)?

Comment: If you describe your problem you will get better solutions, it seems you need Array for the beginning.

Answer (score 7):

That is precisely the use-case of arrays.

```
int[] num = new int[40];

for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
  num[i] = i*4;
}
```

Comment: or `num[i] = 4*i;` :D